# Unfamiliar usage of the phrase "as from"'

Tags: grammar, british-english

This is a paragraph from one of Wodehouse's books.

> Nephew(also the narrator):"Golly!"
>
> Aunt:"You may well say 'Golly!' Anatole, God's gift tothe gastric juices, gone like the dew off the petal of a rose, all through your idiocy. Perhaps you understand now why I want you to go and jump in that pond. I might have known that some hideous disaster would strike this house like a thunderbolt if once you wriggled your way into it and started trying to be clever."
>
> Harsh words, of course, ***as from*** aunt to nephew, but I bore her no resentment. No doubt, if you looked at it from a certain angle, Bertram might be considered to have made something of a floater.

What does the phrase *as from* mean? Does it mean some kind of emphasis? Or are there any implied words which are not present directly,  e.g. as (seen) from? Please give me some examples from the Internet of similar usage. Thank you.

Comment: I think *from aunt to nephew* behaves as a noun phrase.

Answer (score 4):

It is used to emphasize that the bitter words spoken by the aunt to the narrator were much harsh for such a relation of love.

By the phrase *"harsh words, of course, **as from** aunt to nephew,"* the narrator signifies that this level of a cruel harangue is generally not found in a relation between aunt and nephew.

Some examples of the phrase can be:

*Compassion, **as from one enemy to another**, is incredible.*

*Unrestrained care, **as from grandfather to grandson**, is worth enjoying*.*

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This is really helpful. Can you please cite a source/reference as I am unable to find anything on the Internet related to this kind of usage of the phrase 'as from'?

Comment: Can I treat 'as from' equivalent of 'as in from'? 'As in' means 'in the case of '

Comment: Generally, we use "as in from"  to omit a particular word. For example- Compassion, as (shown) from one enemy to another, is incredible, we neglected the use of the word "shown". It is good to make yourself understand the phrase by using "as in from" but while writing use the original phrase (as from) only because it looks somewhat professional for writers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That seems to make sense. This particular phrase 'as from' with the usage you mentioned is not common, I think.  Can you please give an instance(any reference/book/work) where this phrase was used with this meaning?

Comment: Since this phrase seems somewhat confusion to the readers, its usage is on a serious decline (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20from%3B%2Cc0) and hence I couldn't find any genuine example. In case I find it, I will let you know.

Comment: hey.. can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Most usually *as from* is used in providing a time or date. e.g. ***As from*** Monday the business will be in new ownership.

However, in the case you describe here it simply: - ***as (spoken) from aunt to nephew***.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is not *as from*. The correct phrase, which by the way is not technically a phrase at all, is *from... to*: the exchange of harsh words said by the aunt ("from aunt") and addressed to her nephew ("to nephew").

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt. I had a similar explanation. Can you please check my answer above ?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of the preposition 'as'.

Eg 1: You are not performing well as manager.

*As a manager, you are not up to the mark*

Eg 2: As a king, yours does not speak sensible words

*As words spoken by a king, these are not sensible.*

So, the phrase mentioned in the question simply means:

*As (words) from aunt to nephew, these are harsh words.*

Comment: _*'As (words) from...'* _ You got it right! ***As (spoken) from*** in the above answer by WS2 is another equally correct interpretation.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Do you encounter this usage frequently?

Comment: I have early heard it used in this sense, but 'as from' is more often used as short form of 'such as, from...' [example: the law has allowed easier transfer of property between closely related persons, (such) **as from** parents to their offspring.]